# How to use proxy to download a zip file with url

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I have implemented a code to download bhav-copies for all the dates in the stock market. After scraping about 2 years, it seems like my IP got blocked.

This code doesn't work for me.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/APR/fo01APR2014bhav.csv.zip'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

It gives the following error :

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I would like to know how I can use some proxy to get the data. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib.request

proxy_host = '1.2.3.4:8080'    # host and port of your proxy
url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/APR/fo01APR2014bhav.csv.zip'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

For more flexibility, you can use a Proxy Handler - https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

```
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': '1.2.3.4:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib.request.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
```

Comment: The line `response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)` seems to be taking forever, it doesn't finish executing at all.

Comment: @RamHarnish It's dependent on the proxy server. The proxy server would re-directs.

Comment: @RamHarnish I think it's taking more to get a response from the proxy server

Comment: It hasn't solved my problem, it gives this error : `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>`

Comment: It's saying it has timed out connecting to the proxy server

Answer (score 2):

This works fine,

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,lb;q=0.8',

}

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/APR/fo01APR2014bhav.csv.zip"

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

with open("data.zip","wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

if you have proxies,

```
proxy = {"http" : "x.x.x.x:pppp",
         "https" :"x.x.x.x:pppp",
        }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find proxies ?

Comment: Free proxies will not work well.. you can Google for paid proxies like crawlera, geosurf, etc..

Comment: I'll try it out and see if it works, I don't wanna accept before as  then others wouldn't answer it incase this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use proxies to download this file. The code below will work like a charm:

```py
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/APR/fo01APR2014bhav.csv.zip'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)

# Add referer header to bypass "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"
req.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.nseindia.com')
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

# Save it into file.zip
with open("file.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.read())
```

In case you want to get free proxies, visit https://free-proxy-list.net/. Then follow the answer of @pyd at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328368/8009647